# session_start() calling a cpanel file despite running on nginx

Tags: php, nginx, apache2

I am testing some php scripts on my RPI 3+ running nginx on OSMC. All works well except that I am getting the following error when calling session_start()

> Warning: session_start(): open(/var/cpanel/php/sessions/imh-php72/sess_898c9fa9f876bce0a455e3ab3af9b407, O_RDWR) failed: No such file or directory

why is it trying to call something in a cpanel directory when I am running it on nginx?

Yes, the scripts do normally run on my production cpanel server. All I did was copy the files across to my local RPI installation, and now I get this error.

Originally I did install apache2 on the RPI and then purged it when I went with nginx.

I don't have the faintest idea where to even start on trying to figure this out. Can anyone please help?

On the RPI I have OSMC running nginx and I installed php7.3. which shows up when I run php -v, but my phpinfo gives a different story:

System Linux Kodi 4.14.78-4-osmc #1 SMP PREEMPT Wed Dec 12 17:58:11 UTC 2018 armv7l

Build Date Sep 23 2019 12:22:30

Server API FPM/FastCGI

Virtual Directory Support disabled

Configuration File (php.ini) Path /etc/php/7.0/fpm

Loaded Configuration File /etc/php/7.0/fpm/php.ini

Scan this dir for additional .ini files /etc/php/7.0/fpm/conf.d

Additional .ini files parsed /etc/php/7.0/fpm/conf.d/10-mysqlnd.ini, /etc/php/7.0/fpm/conf.d/10-opcache.ini, /etc/php/7.0/fpm/conf.d/10-pdo.ini, /etc/php/7.0/fpm/conf.d/15-xml.ini, /etc/php/7.0/fpm/conf.d/20-calendar.ini, /etc/php/7.0/fpm/conf.d/20-ctype.ini, /etc/php/7.0/fpm/conf.d/20-dom.ini, /etc/php/7.0/fpm/conf.d/20-exif.ini, /etc/php/7.0/fpm/conf.d/20-fileinfo.ini, /etc/php/7.0/fpm/conf.d/20-ftp.ini, /etc/php/7.0/fpm/conf.d/20-gettext.ini, /etc/php/7.0/fpm/conf.d/20-iconv.ini, /etc/php/7.0/fpm/conf.d/20-json.ini, /etc/php/7.0/fpm/conf.d/20-mbstring.ini, /etc/php/7.0/fpm/conf.d/20-mysqli.ini, /etc/php/7.0/fpm/conf.d/20-pdo_mysql.ini, /etc/php/7.0/fpm/conf.d/20-phar.ini, /etc/php/7.0/fpm/conf.d/20-posix.ini, /etc/php/7.0/fpm/conf.d/20-readline.ini, /etc/php/7.0/fpm/conf.d/20-shmop.ini, /etc/php/7.0/fpm/conf.d/20-simplexml.ini, /etc/php/7.0/fpm/conf.d/20-sockets.ini, /etc/php/7.0/fpm/conf.d/20-sysvmsg.ini, /etc/php/7.0/fpm/conf.d/20-sysvsem.ini, /etc/php/7.0/fpm/conf.d/20-sysvshm.ini, /etc/php/7.0/fpm/conf.d/20-tokenizer.ini, /etc/php/7.0/fpm/conf.d/20-wddx.ini, /etc/php/7.0/fpm/conf.d/20-xmlreader.ini, /etc/php/7.0/fpm/conf.d/20-xmlwriter.ini, /etc/php/7.0/fpm/conf.d/20-xsl.ini

I am guessing something got totally messed up with my installations, but I have no idea where to start.

thanks for any help or suggestions. I am a linux newbie.

Noel

Answer (score 1):

I still don't know why it is trying to write to a cpanel directory, but simply creating the specified missing directory,

```
 sudo mkdir -p /var/cpanel/php/sessions/imh-php72/
```

and giving it write permissions solved the problem.